# Prove that $ {2n \choose n} = {2n \choose n+1} + {2n \choose n-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to prove that.

$\displaystyle {2n \choose n} = \displaystyle {2n \choose n+1} + {2n \choose n-1}$

Is this necessarily true / how should I try to tackle it if it is?

Comment: Sorry, I typed my equation wrong, going to fix it!

Comment: Try $n=2$ to try to show it's not  true.

Comment: As others have noted, what you have is not generally true. In fact, $$\begin{align*}\color{red}{\binom{2n+2}{n+1}}-2\binom{2n}n &=\color{red}{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}+\binom{2n+1}n}- 2\binom{2n}n\\
&=\color{blue}{\binom{2n+1}{n+1}}-\binom{2n}n+\color{green}{\binom{2n-1}n}- \binom{2n}n\\
&=\color{blue}{\binom{2n}{n+1}+\binom{2n}n}-\binom{2n}n+\color{green}{\binom{2n}n+\binom{2n}{n-1}}-\binom{2n}n\\
&=\binom{2n}{n+1}+\binom{2n}{n-1}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What happened to your plan to fix the question, @op_finales ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true in general that ${2n\choose n}={2n\choose n-1}+{2n\choose n+1}$. For instance, if $n=2$ then ${4\choose 2}=6$, while ${4\choose 1}+{4\choose 3}=8$.

Answer (score 0):

In general,
$$
\binom{2n}{n-1}=\binom{2n}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\frac{\binom{2n}{n-1}+\binom{2n}{n+1}}{\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{2n}{n+1}
$$
which is $1$ if and only if $n=1$.